# How can I pass default props as function in functional component

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am using functional components in application. Below is my code.

```
 const Modal = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const { handleClose, children, ...rest } = props;

  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    handleOpen() {
      setOpen(true);
    },

    handleClose() {
      setOpen(false);
    }
  }));

  const modalHandleClose = () => {
    ref.current.handleClose();
  };

  return (
    <Dialog
      open={open}
      onClose={handleClose}
      scroll="body"
      {...rest}
      disableBackdropClick
    >
      {children}
    </Dialog>
  );
});
```

In above component I want pass a default prop for handleClose as below

```
Modal.defaultProps = {
  handleCLose: modalHandleClose
};
```

but I am getting error that "modalHandleClose not defined". What can I try to resolve this?

Comment: I think that is beecause modalHandleClose is not defined enywhere, try with `handleCLose = () => { /* default handle close function body */ }`

Comment: I'm confused why you are passing both a `handleClose` prop callback function ***and*** wanting to to use the React ref. Seems the default prop value you are wanting to set would be that of the `Dialog` component.

Comment: @DrewReese. this is my common component . I have different action onClose of some of the component so , I am passing as props . In some case I have default action onClose . Thats the reason I am passing default handle close .

Comment: Nicholas's solution below should be what you need. BTW, you don't need to mark a prop required if you are providing a fallback value, the fact that you are providing a fallback sort of precludes the prop being required.

Comment: @DrewReese if I will mark as required then it will ask again for defaultProps.

Answer (score 0):

React's `defaultProps` can't do that, since it's a static property of the component. It cannot access anything that only will exist once the component renders.

I would instead recommend using default values when destructuring the props:

```
const Modal = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const modalHandleClose = () => {
    ref.current.handleClose();
  };

  const { 
    handleClose = modalHandleClose, // <----- default value 
    children, 
    ...rest 
  } = props;
```

Comment: your solutions is working as functionally . but I am getting this 'The prop `handleClose` is marked as required in `Modal`, but its value is `undefined`' . When I make props validation is required.